# Pass html variables to PHP using "ID" not "Name"

Tags: php, html

I have HTML code like below

```
<input type = "textarea" id="sentence1"> Here is my sentence </textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="sentence2" value="This is another sentence">
```

PHP:

```
$_POST['sentence1']  //shows nothing
$_POST['sentence2'] // works fine
```

I want to get the value of sentence1 also But i have such a scattered code that for textarea i can't change "id" to "name" otherwise i'll have to make lot of changes in different files.

I have to transfer both sentences to PHP so please help me how can i do that?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Sorry i did not understand what you want to say.

Comment: From the [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq): *When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you're getting value from the community. (If you don't do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)*

Comment: Oh i see. Actually i'm new user but don't worry now i'll take care of this option.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is wrong. You should start using a browser with HTML validation, that would've caught it.

```
<textarea name="sentence1" id="sentence1"> Here is my sentence </textarea>
```

`<input type="hidden" name="sentence2" value="This is another sentence" />`

Comment: Yes, this is what i wanted. 
Thank you so much.
It is working.

Answer (score 5):

There is no input `type="textarea"`. You cannot use the `id` attribute for the `name` attribute. This is not how it will get transmitted and there is no way to change that from plain HTML. Form `<input>` elements are transmitted with their `name` and `value` attributes.

Please refresh you knowledge about [HTML Form elements and attributes](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/elements-form)

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
<input type = "textarea" id="sentence1"> Here is my sentence </textarea>
```

into

```
<textarea id="sentence1" name="sentence1"> Here is my sentence </textarea>
```

and your PHP will work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've corrected the `<input type="textarea">` mistake. If I understand your needs correctly, you know that the form only passes the value of the `name` attribute, and not the `id`, but you can't change that easily.

My suggestion would be to add a script to either change the value of the `name` attribute into that of the `id`, or copy the entire attribute so it's available under both the `name` and the `id`:

```
<script>  
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++)  
    inputs[i].parentNode.appendChild(inputs[i].cloneNode(false));  
</script>
```

and add it at the end of your pages. do the same for textareas.

Answer (score 0):

You can't (at least not using plain HTML). The W3C recommendation regarding form handling and processing states

> A control's "control name" is given by
>   its name attribute. The scope of the
>   name attribute for a control within a
>   FORM element is the FORM element.

and

> A form data set is a sequence of
>   **control-name**/current-value pairs
>   constructed from successful controls

See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html).

You can use Javascript to add the `name`-attribute dynamically to all form elements without the respective attribute.

Answer (score 0):

> But i have such a scattered code that for textarea i can't change "id" to "name" otherwise i'll have to make lot of changes in different files.
>   Then probably that's where you should start. (Note: A input/textarea element may have both a name and an id attribute.)